# Securing Files/Folders in MVC

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I want to secure a folder so that only logged in users can access it. This folder has a set of images that only logged in users should be able to download.

There are two ways that I can do this.

1. Give the users a direct link to the image file
2. Create a Download action and allow them to download the file through that

My problem is in either of these cases, how should I block access to the folder and allow only the logged in users? If I to create an action, I can secure it through `Authorize` attribute. But it doesn't secure direct access to the folder.

I tried using config below within a web.config file inside the folder that I want to secure. but it can be accessed by anonymous users.

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your images within in the `App_Data` root folder - this will stop direct image file downloads outside of your download action.

e.g. Access to `http://www.example.com/App_Data/Secure_Images/image1.jpg` will not be possible because ASP.NET will prevent access.

Answer (score 0):

By default, regular files do not go thru the asp.net pipeline.  In order to make them do so you need to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

After you do that, your authorization settings will work.